# What is the string encoding for structures passed to Win32 async callback functions?

Tags: winapi, character-encoding

I can't seem to find the documentation for this - when calling the Win32 API [DnsQueryEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/nf-windns-dnsqueryex) or [DnsServiceBrowse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/nf-windns-dnsservicebrowse), for async operation you pass in a callback of type [DNS_QUERY_COMPLETION_ROUTINE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/nc-windns-dns_query_completion_routine).  This callback receives a pointer `PDNS_RECORD` (the definition doesn't use `PDNS_RECORDA` or `PDNS_RECORDW`, just `PDNS_RECORD`).  That structure has a field `pName`, which is documented as:

> A pointer to a string that represents the domain name of the record set. This must be in the string format that corresponds to the function called, such as ANSI, Unicode, or UTF8.

But, those async functions don't have different variants for different encodings, and I'm not constructing this structure, the library is providing it.  How do I know what encoding the `pName` field uses?

Comment: The only hint here is that `DNS_RECORD` is typedef'd to `DNS_RECORDW` inside an `#ifdef UNICODE` gate. Still odd that the API call itself (`DnsQueryEx`) has only one implementation, and that implementation doesn't specify the character encoding (in contrast to, say, `CommandLineToArgvW`). I'm lost on this one.

Comment: usually you look in callback for ip (v4 or v6) address. so check for records with type `DNS_TYPE_A` ( `DNS_A_DATA`) and `DNS_TYPE_AAAA` ( `DNS_AAAA_DATA`) - both not depend from ansi/unicode. however if you check for instance `DNS_PTR_DATA` (`DNS_TYPE_CNAME`, `DNS_TYPE_NS`) records (which point to ansi or unicode string) - *This must be in the string format that corresponds to the function called* - `DnsQueryEx` use unicode. so in this records - will be unicode strings - this is `*W` records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you note yourself

> This must be in the string format that corresponds to the function
> called, such as ANSI, Unicode, or UTF8.

the `DnsQueryEx` and `DnsServiceBrowse` take Unicode strings as input ( [`DNS_QUERY_REQUEST.QueryName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/ns-windns-dns_query_request) and [`DNS_SERVICE_BROWSE_REQUEST.QueryName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/ns-windns-dns_service_browse_request)). so on output it also must use Unicode format. [`DNS_QUERY_RESULT.pQueryRecords`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/ns-windns-dns_query_result) point to `DNS_RECORDW`